# Реально ли реализовать с помощью одного запроса MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

К крону нужно прикрутить скрипт, реально ли реализовать чисто на мускуле?

- Если в таблице tab0 поле flag0 == '1' тогда поле isshow = '0'
- Если в таблице tab0 поле flag0 > '1' тогда поле flag0 = flag0 - 1
- // Если в таблице tab0 поле flag0 == '0' тогда ничего не делать //

Начал с:

```
UPDATE tab0 SET isshow = '0' WHERE flag0 = '1'
```

как сделать условие и отнять единичку - не понял. Подскажите...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  `tab0`
SET
  `isshow` = IF (`flag0` = 1, 0, `isshow`),
  `flag0` = IF (`flag0` > 1, `flag0` - 1, `flag0`)
```

[MySQL IF](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Control_flow_functions.html)

Да и cron не всегда нужен - [MySQL EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, если вы хорошо знаете mysql event может быть подскажите как "правильно" сделать событие mysql чтобы оно выполнялось один раз в сутки, в любое время (ну скажем в полночь)?

Comment: подобное:

CREATE EVENT myevent

    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 HOUR

    DO

    UPDATE `tab0` SET `isshow` = IF (`flag0` = 1, 0, `isshow`), `flag0` = IF (`flag0` > 1, `flag0` - 1, `flag0`) WHERE 1

верно? и где его запустить, скажем в phpmyadmin в консоле однажды? если сервер перезагружается раз в неделю будет ли выполнятся это?